# How to do pip install for git repos

Tags: python, pip

I had done a pip freeze and one of the line in requirement file is a  git repo  as en-core-web-lg @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5.tar.gz

I have tried installing it with

```
pip3 install -e en-core-web-lg @ git+https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

It resulted in an error as

```
line 97, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'@'"
```

Comment: `pip` sees the `@` as a package name and not as an identifier for a location. Have you tried without the spaces around `@`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

In your original URL, the `@` is unnecessary. Nevertheless, `-e` flag and `git+https` implies that you provide a `#egg=your_package_name` at the end of the URL specifying the package that will be editable and installed. This seems incompatible with the tarball URL as far as I could test.

So just go with the above URL, I guess it's what you need.